# I am trying to create a calculator program

Tags: python, string, split, calculator, enumerate

I am writing a code that removes '√' symbol from a string and get's the index of it, By using the 'enumerate' function in python, I have already made an functioning calculator but I am improving it.

Code:

```
cal = input(">>> ")
for i, c in enumerate(cal):
    if c == '√':
        cal = cal[0:i]+cal[i+1:]
print(cal)
```

Input:

```
>>> 123√456√789√123
```

Output:

```
123456√89√13
```

I am not getting the right output when I remove a character from the string the enumerate function messes up the index , So I can't figure it out.
[My first time using stackover flow Don't judge]

Comment: You can't modify something while looping over it because it will mess things up.

Comment: Because, for example, if you get to the fifth index of the string and remove it, then the loop will move on and try to get the sixth index. But since you removed the fifth index, everything has been moved back, so you end up skipping the thing which used to be at the sixth index but is now at the fifth.

Comment: How about `cal.replace('√', '')`?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments. You have made the classic error of editing a list whilst looping thru it. The edits will change the list, so the positions will be incorrect.

a good solution is this:

```py
cal = '123√456√789√123'

cal = cal.replace('√','')
cal
```

Which returns this:

```
'123456789123'
```